# Why can't I install Unity UI Toolkit?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, installation, package, ui-toolkit

I want to use UI Toolkit for my project.

When I try to install it using com.unity.ui something strange happens. 
When the installation is finished, the package appears and immediately disappears from my manager.

I'm using version 2021.3.6f1. 
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `com.unity.ui` package in 2021.3 anymore. While UI Toolkit was always a core module in Unity, the Runtime (the `UIDocument` `MonoBehaviour`) support that `com.unity.ui` added has also been moved as a core module in Unity in 2021.x. You should be good to go!